# Use TextFieldParser on multiple lines of .txt file in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, file-io

I'm working on a project for a VB Programming class, and I'm trying to create a player registration and profile program. We are not allowed to use a database, as our professor wants us to use a .txt file for this project.

I've figured out how to write the information to a .txt file and can parse out the first line of the .txt file to display the information in the right fields, but I cannot figure out how to parse out multiple lines. I need to read a .txt file and find a specific line and use all the information in that line to fill out form fields.

Here is what I have to parse the first line.

```
 Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO
 Imports System.IO

Public Class Profile

Private PlayerInfoParser As TextFieldParser
Friend index As Integer = Home.cbPlayerLookUp.SelectedIndex

Private Sub Profile_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim FileString As String = "MasterRoster.txt"

    Try
        PlayerInfoParser = New TextFieldParser(FileString)
        PlayerInfoParser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited
        PlayerInfoParser.SetDelimiters(",")
    Catch
        MessageBox.Show("Error")
    End Try


    Dim FieldString() As String

    If Not PlayerInfoParser.EndOfData Then
        FieldString = PlayerInfoParser.ReadFields()
        txtFirstNameProfile.Text = FieldString(0)
        txtLastNameProfile.Text = FieldString(1)
    Else

    End If
```

Currently this will only display the first line of the .txt file ("MaserRoster.txt"). I cannot figure out how to get it to check the second line.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What is the format of each Record of your Text file? I am gathering that it is one record per line and comma delineated.

Comment: why you don't open a file and iterate through every single line

Comment: @MarkHall They are all strings. I'm just trying to display them.

Comment: @fernando I'm not sure I know what you mean. Could you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that you are not looping through your Lines you are only executing ReadField one time, enclose it in `While` statement instead of an `If` statement then you can iterate through all of your lines.

```
While Not PlayerInfoParser.EndOfData
    FieldString = PlayerInfoParser.ReadFields()
    txtFirstNameProfile.Text = FieldString(0)
    txtLastNameProfile.Text = FieldString(1)
End While
```

---

As I mentioned in my comment I would probably just use the File object that is in VB.net. It has a ReadLines Method that will read all of the lines in at one time, then you can iterate through them and parse them. I created a custom class that will hold the information that you are reading from the file and then creating a list of that class. You can then select which record you want and display it.

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Dim playerList As List(Of player) = New List(Of player)
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        txtFirstNameProfile.Text = playerList(1).firstname
        txtLastNameProfile.Text = playerList(1).lastname

    End Sub
    Private Sub Profile_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


        Dim FileString As String = "MasterRoster.txt"

        Dim values() As String = File.ReadAllLines(FileString)
        Dim FieldString() As String
        If Not values.Length = 0 Then
            For Each s As String In values
                FieldString = s.Split(","c)
                playerList.Add(New player(FieldString(0), FieldString(1)))
            Next
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
Class player
    Dim mFirst As String
    Dim mLast As String
    Public ReadOnly Property firstname
        Get
            Return mFirst
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property lastname
        Get
            Return mLast
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Sub New(first As String, last As String)
        mFirst = first
        mLast = last
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return mFirst & "," & mLast
    End Function
End Class
```

Or if you just want to grab a single line something like this should work.

```
Dim values() As String = File.ReadAllLines(FileString)
Dim FieldString() As String
If Not values.Length < index Then  'The index is zero based
    FieldString = values(index).Split(","c)
    txtFirstNameProfile.Text = FieldString(0)
    txtLastNameProfile.Text = FieldString(1)
End If
```

And finally if you want to keep using the `TextFieldParser` you can use something like this.

```
While Not PlayerInfoParser.EndOfData
    FieldString = PlayerInfoParser.ReadFields()
    PlayerList.Add(New player(FieldString(0), FieldString(1)))
End While
```

Comment: This worked. I also need the ability to choose a particular line of the .txt file. So when I choose a particular player I need to pull his line and take all his info.

Comment: So if I just need to read and parse line <index> how would I specifically use just that line?

Comment: I am working on another example, that doesn't use the legacy VB6 style but will read all of the lines of the file in at one time. You can then select which line then parse or parse them into a list then select the values from the list.

Comment: The second part you posted was PERFECT. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This a very simple exercise to read every single line using a fictitious text file, this is the content of the text file:

```
player1, score: 0.385, games: 5
player2, score: 0.345, games: 3
player3, score: 0.235, games: 7
player4, score: 0.319, games: 6
player5, score: 0.296, games: 9
```

this is the code to read every single line at a time:

```
Module Module1
Sub Main()

    Dim file As New IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\players.txt")
    Dim line As String

    While file.Peek <> -1
        line = file.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine(line)
    End While

    Console.Read()
End Sub
End Module
```